# Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have this problem :
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0

I'm trying :

- change my buildpath java1.5 to java1.8
- then maven>update to my project

But the issue is still here and buildpath is still java1.5

Do you have an idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `workspace>>Project folder>>.settings >>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`. Open and edit it as per your convenience. Let me know if it solves the problem.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.8"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

`